# SEO in backbone.js - How to make google index the page after the page is being rendered?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, seo, phantomjs, google-crawlers

I am building my website with backbone js application framework and I am changing the urls with the html5 push state. All the content is being rendered through the js and basically the dom is more or less empty before the page render method (there is just a core structure without any content). I assume that this is very bad for search engines, because  bots won't crawl the actual content of the website.

So is there any workaround or I will have to render the content with some server side technology on the first init? I am really hoping that's not the only option, because I already have the complete logic, models, templates and everything written in js...

I've heard that phantom.js can do this job? Would it be easier to accomplish that using node.js for server side scripting?

Comment: @kennebec Of course it can be navigated to, there are separate links for each page. I am using html5 push state to change pages.

Comment: I suggest you looking into https://github.com/airbnb/rendr from AirBnb, they have developed the solution to take care this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is there any workaround

No

> or I will have to render the content with some server side technology on the first init?

The point of using pushState and having real URLs is that it lets you failover to server side technology (and to generating initial views using server side, which is usually faster then doing loading a default view in JS and then changing it after making extra Ajax requests).

> I've heard that phantom.js can do this job?

I support you could use phantom.js to look at the URL, request the initial page, run the JS needed to change it to the page at the specified URL and then server that up… but it sounds like a pretty inefficient solution.

Comment: So, you are telling me that phantom.js can't help me in this situation? What if I switch back to hashbangs? It's gonna be a complete nightmare if I'll have to re-create the whole logic, views and models with php! Previously i was doing it like so, but I was serving the templates already filled with the content using the php (my models have been created in php), so it wasn't a big deal... Please advise as I am starting to be really desperate!

Comment: "What if I switch back to hashbangs?" — Then search engines still get bad data, and links break for people who don't have JS turned on.

Comment: Yeah I've heard that phantom can do the job, but poorly, that's why I am asking for the opinion from somebody who has more experience with that... What about node? Would it be easier if I were using it for the server side scripting? Thanks...

Comment: If you use Node then you would be using JavaScript for your server side logic. If you've got a decent separation of concerns for your client side code, then it should let you reuse a lot of your logic.

Comment: So what is your advise, what should I finally do? To recreate the same logic in php? :(

Comment: Yeah, that's what I tough about the node... So actually that is the best approach? I am really, really newbie to node, just started doing some basic examples yesterday, so please have understanding...

Comment: I can't tell you if your PHP skills compared to your node skills would mean that reimplementing some code (that I haven't seen) would be faster or slower in PHP or node.

Comment: Well... my php skills are far better then node, so until i get more familiar with node it would be definitely faster for me to recreate the logic in php, but I was hoping that I'll be able to avoid this somehow. And by ur opinion is that something that has to be done to achieve some descent rating on google?

Comment: If you want context to be indexed, it has to be visible without JS.

Comment: Yeah, that's what i initially thought... Damn it! Thanks for your time, I will close this discussion for now and continue learning node.